# How can I get a dynamic value of href and id's of the card in React JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

This is my first question in stackoverflow, I am still learning how to code and it might be a newbie question.

But, is it possible to have a dynamic `href` and `id` values when I want to map my data with axios to become cards? Because if I run my code, the card that will work (one that can collapse) is just the first one, the others did not work. This is my code (sorry the code isnt the same with the real file in my vscode cos my real file was becoming a chaos.)

```
render() {
  const mobillist = this.state.dataku.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid" style={{ marginTop: "100px" }}>
        <div id="accordion">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-header">
              <a className="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#colla">
                {item.model} - {item.tahun}
              </a>
            </div>

            <div id="colla" className="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
              <div className="card-body">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col">
                    <h4> ini menu 1 </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col">
                    <center> <h4> ini menu 2  </h4></center>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
    return (
      <div>
        {mobillist}
      </div>
```

Comment: There's a few errors in the code your provided, like `const mobillist` is different to `{mobilist}` and the way you render. Also can you explain what you want exactly?

Comment: what I want to do is to map my database data and use the data in the cards. However, all of the card wont do "up and down" perfectly (just the first one) cos, with my code, all href and id have same values. All I want to do, is how can I have different href and id values for each of my card. THx

Comment: Oh ya, I was using axios by the way. but I did not write the axios get code in my code cos it is too long

Comment: You can get different id by using the `index` like this `const mobillist = this.state.dataku.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid" key={index} style={{ marginTop: "100px" }}>
      ...
      </div>
    )
  }`

Comment: and in your href you do this `<a href={{'#'+index}}></a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use unique ID for every href using `index` value in the map and also map the `index` in accordion `div`. See the below code for sample

```
render() {
    const mobillist = this.state.dataku.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid" style={{ marginTop: "100px" }}>
        <div id="accordion">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-header">
              <a className="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href={"#colla"+ index}>
                {item.model} - {item.tahun}
              </a>
            </div>

            <div id={"colla"+ index} className="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
              <div className="card-body">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col">
                    <h4> ini menu 1 </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col">
                    <center> <h4> ini menu 2  </h4></center>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
    return (
      <div>
        {mobillist}
      </div>
```

Comment: react requires key indexing. You should add `key={index}` to first `div` in `<div className="container-fluid" ..>`